# Amazon Prime Video for Android TV

Tags: android, amazon, android-nougat, android-tv

Android set top box (shipped rooted by manufacturer):
[KII_PRO_NOUGAT_DTV_GTVS_VSADV](https://androidpctv.com/review-mecool-kii-pro)

Amazon Prime Video for Android TV via Google Play installed. App works and play trailer - but not actually prime videos itself

When link is opened from web browser it redirect to Google Play and says this version of app is not compatible with device, and offers to uninstall app only.

Looking for any alternative app, fork, or an older version (4 or 3) of that app.
[com.amazon.amazonvideo.livingroom](https://android-apk.org/com.amazon.amazonvideo.livingroom/50261136-prime-video-android-tv)

Comment: amazonvideo app is not even visible in app drawer https://android.stackexchange.com/q/234437

Comment: Interesting problem.  I'm not currently aware of an alternative app (but I hope there is one!), but I can suggest letting Amazon know about the issue.  It's in their financial interest to have Amazon Prime Video work on every device.  Now for getting that message to the right person at Amazon, that's no easy task.  My experiences with Amazon support have resulted in me concluding that it's more productive to talk to a black hole.

Comment: looking at play store ratings and reviews they don't care ;) do you think this can be related to rooting? i tested on magisk systemless phone and it works. but this box has /xbin/su in system. tried older version 4 same problem

Comment: Yup.  I never quite understand why people like Amazon.  I sometimes buy things there, but I almost never enjoy the experience.  Their website is horrible in most ways, and their customer service is even worse.  Regarding your rooting question, yes, I think it's possible they detect the device is rooted and don't allow their apps to work on rooted devices, but I have not read reports of that (I haven't looked for such reports, so I don't have data either way).

Comment: You're welcome.  Yes, it's a weird English artifact that "pre-installed" and "pre-rooted" have completely different connotations... but English is a weird language.  I was confused by the difference of what I thought you were trying to say in your question versus what you said in your comment.  Since your comment was real clear, I edited your question accordingly.  I'm glad I guessed right! :)